# prolog, list with proper brackets as result

Tags: prolog

I am wondering how to get a nice proper looking list with the elements I have! I've been trying to look up stuff on this but none of the actual examples I've found seem to actually work

Here is one method I found on the web:

```
create_list(Item, List, [Item|List]).
```

if I run this query:

```
Hi = [1,2], Hey = [3,4], create_list(Hi, Hey, Output).
```

The result gets weird:

```
Output = [[1,2], 3,4]
```

The brackets are all wrong!
It should be:

```
[[1,2], [3,4]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The brackets are all wrong! It should be:
>
> ```
> [[1,2], [3,4]]
> ```

This is because your `create_list` uses `[Item|List]`. If you wanted brackets around `[3,4]` to remain in place, replace `[Item|List]` with `[Item,List]`. Of course `List` has incorrect meaning now, so I would rename it, as follows:

```
list_of_two(First, Last, [First, Last]).
```

This would not work for more than two items, however. Your original one rule would work, like this:

```
create_list([1,2],[],O1), create_list([3,4],O1,O2), create_list([5,6],O2,O3).
```

This produces

```
[[5, 6], [3, 4], [1, 2]]
```

in the `O3` list.

Comment: Thanks however: See, if I all of a sudden now have this instead: A = [1,2], B = [3,4], C = [5,6], D = [A, B], list_of_two(C, D, Output) then it will produce a bracket too many: Output = [ [5,6] , [ [1,2],[3,4]]]!

Comment: @Deragon The result depends on how you use your predicate. Take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast with other languages, a list is a very basic datastructure in Prolog:

`[]` is/creates an empty list
`[1]` is/creates a list with a single element
`[1,2,3,4,....,n]` is/creates a list with `n` elements
`[1|[2,3,4]]` is/creates a list by inserting `1` in the list `[2,3,4]` (the result is `[1,2,3,4]`)

So, you don't need a predicate to "create" a list: if you have `n` elements just put them in brackets; if the elements are generated recursively, use `|` to create a list with the new element. For example:

```
put_in_list(A1,A2,A3, L):- L = [A1,A2,A3].
```

alternatively:

```
put_in_list(A1,A2,A3, [A1,A2,A3]).
```

also:

```
generate(0, []).
generate(N, [ [N, NN]| Rest ]):-
   NN is N-1,
   NNN is N-2,
   generate(NNN, Rest).
```

All in all, you should be careful with types; in your case, you have a list of numbers (let's call it X) and you want a list of lists of numbers (so this would be a list of Xs). The problem was created when you gave a list of Xs as an argument instead of an X to a predicate.

Comment: Hi, I still feel a bit lost on how to properly use it more than once.Like: Hi = [1,2], Hey = [3,4], put_in_list(Hi, Hey, Out), put_in_list(Hi, Out, Out2). Out2 will return [ [X,X], [ [X,X], [X,X]  ]], like, instead of: [ [X,X], [X,X], [X,X] ], so instead of three elements, it will be two elements!